# HTML / CSS - adjust font-size to fill parent height and width

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-size

I have a `<div>` element that resizes as the browser window resizes.

Inside the `<div>` I have a paragraph of text:

```
<div style="width:80%; height:80%; margin:10%;">
    <p>Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.</p>
</div>
```

*I want the text to change `font-size` as I resize the `<div>`, so that the text will occuypy 100% of the available space.*

How can I achieve this effect?
Would it be with a percentage font-size?
Would I have to use Javascript?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A 100% font size would look at the size of the font it's using and go to 100% of its default size, it would not look at your box's height.

Comment: @animuson Thanks for the info! That's what I thought. Any solutions?

Comment: what does margin:80% do?

Comment: That was a bug, thanks @Jawad!

Answer (score 6):

There's a jquery plugin for this: http://fittextjs.com/

Comment: Oh, and don't you dare let us catch you using FitText on paragraph text. This is for gigantic display text only!

Comment: Thanks for the plugin! Anything more lightweight? jQuery is a bit obese for my good looking website. :)

Comment: Is there anything that supports paragraphs?

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="change" style="margin:10%;"> 
    <p>Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.</p> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
#change { 
    width: 80%; 
    height: 80%; 
    border: 1px solid black; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    font-size: 1em; 
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function() { 
    while( $('#change div').height() > $('#change').height() ) { 
        $('#change div').css('font-size', (parseInt($('#change div').css('font-size')) - 1) + "px" ); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: taken from - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112660/how-to-resize-automatically-a-font-size-inside-a-div

Answer (score 0):

`fittext.js` did not work correctly for me (plugin for jQuery, as well as derived jquery-free version), nor with using of compressor attribute, so I found another solution:

**http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/?whichScript=text_fit_in_box**
(someone's another work)

which works perfectly for me - longer texts as well as shorter texts.

It just do not react to resize of window (it works just once on loading of page), so I have written this short code to run it automatically after each window resize (it works for me):

```
<script>
      function calculate_font_sizes()
      {
        fitTextInBox('login-h1');
        fitTextInBox('subtittle');
      }
      calculate_font_sizes();
      window.addEventListener('resize', calculate_font_sizes);

</script>
```

I hope it can help to someone.

Comment: @Zeus Zdravkov: Which way?

Answer (score -2):

Check out the vw properties in css

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: Vw is for width. The user asked for width and height. And his example is not for body. So, your answer is unuseful.

Comment: I believe as the width increases the height increases as well.