# How can text be scaled according to its parent in css

Tags: jquery, html, css, font-size

How can i make some text font-size scale to the div in such way the proportion text-size/divsize stays the same?
In other words, when I resize the div, I need the text to resize with it like if it's only an image scaling.

How can I achieve this? preferable css only.

This can be a webkit only solution. I don't need it to be compatible with the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this properly without relying on Javascript.

If you want to use a CSS-only solution whether it is even close to possible depends on how the `div` is being resized - if it's based on viewport then you can achieve this (albeit in a very hacky and work-intensive, difficult to maintain fashion) with CSS media queries like below, if it's done some other way you probably have to resort to JS for any solution.

div {
    width: 50%;
    font-size: 72px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
    div {
        font-size: 36px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    div {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}

And so on.  Obviously this is an approximate/imperfect solution at best and that is assuming your `div` is sized relative to the window (which makes `@media` queries relevant).  Otherwise you probably have to use JavaScript.

I recently stumbled across [**FitText**](http://fittextjs.com/) which is a JS plugin that does exactly what you're asking.  Another option is [**BigText**](https://github.com/zachleat/BigText).  Both require jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

As answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112660/how-to-automatically-resize-the-size-of-text-inside-a-div), [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MYSVL/1064/) may be a good example to look at.

For a CSS-only solution, at least according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431411/pure-css-to-make-font-size-responsive-based-on-dynamic-amount-of-characters), it would appear that you could use vw units to do this, like so:

```
div {
    font-size: 1.5vw;
}
```

However, the question I linked to (and [this article](http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)) say that it does not work flawlessly in some browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Well why not transform the element with `transform: scale`?

```
-webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
-moz-transform: scale(1.5);
-ms-transform: scale(1.5);
-o-transform: scale(1.5);
transform: scale(1.5);
```